# Geometric Interpretation: Parallel forms are harmonic

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.

> The canonical volume form $\mu=\sqrt{\det g_{ij}}\,\mathrm{d}x^1\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^m$ is parallel with respect to the induced Levi-Civita conection $\nabla$ on $\Omega^m(M)$ hence $\mu$ is also harmonic.

Using local normal coordinates I am able to see that $\nabla\mu=0$ and also, since $\delta\mu=(-1)^{m(m+1)+1}\star\mathrm{d}\star\mu=(-1)^{m(m+1)+1}\star\mathrm{d}(1)=0$ and $\mathrm{d}\mu=0$, that $\Delta_{\operatorname{Hod}}\mu=0$, i.e. that $\mu$ is harmonic.

However, why does $\nabla\omega=0$ imply $\Delta_{\operatorname{Hod}}\omega=0$ for $\omega\in\Omega^p(M)$? (E.g. stated by [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Parallel_field).)

**Edit:** Is there some geometric interpretation of this statement?

Comment: The fact that the volume form is parallel implies that infinitesimal deformations of the volume form act exactly linearly. Since the Levi-Civita connection controls also the cotangent deformations, this implies that the volume form expands linearly in every possible direction. This is stronger than $\Delta \mu = 0$!

Comment: @GlenWheeler What exactly do you mean by "stronger than $\Delta\mu=0$? In fact, how can we interpret a solution of the Laplace equation on an arbitrary manifold?

Comment: See the answer for the first question. For the second: It isn't an arbitrary solution of the Laplacian, it's the Laplacian acting on the volume form.

Comment: what's your definition of $\nabla\omega$?

Comment: @rmdmc89: The usual one: $(\nabla \omega) (X_1, \dots, X_p, Y) = (\nabla _Y \omega) (X_1, \dots, X_p)$, with $\nabla$ being initially the Levi-Civita connection, extended using the Leibniz formula for covariant derivatives acting on tensors.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If $\nabla\omega=0$ then also $d\omega=0$, since $d\omega$ is the skew-symmetrization of $\nabla\omega$ (this is true for any torsion-free connection, whether it's Levi-Civita or not). On the other hand (just for Levi-Civita), if $\omega$ is parallel then also $*\omega$ is parallel (since $*$ is defined in terms of the metric). Thus also $d*\omega=0$, so also $\delta\omega=0$ and $\Delta\omega=(d\delta+\delta d)\omega=0$.

Comment: What is your definition of $\nabla\omega$?