# An inequality of p forms on Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $(M^n,g)$ is an Riemannian manifold with boundary, $w$ is any $p$-form  in $A^p(M)$, then we have following inequality
$$\|\nabla w\|^2\geq \frac{\|d w\|^2}{p+1}+\frac{\|\delta w\|^2}{n-p+2}$$
where the norm is induced norm on vector bundle by $g$, $d$ is the differential of form and $\delta$ is the codifferential. I am not familar with $p$-forms. Can any one show me some references about this inequality? I am interested in the characterization of equality. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Do you have any reference at all about this inequality? Where have you seen it?

Comment: @ Asaf Shachar I found this inequality in the paper "On the first eigenvalue of the Dirichlet-to-Neumann operators on forms" (15), it gives reference but it is non-English, so I think there might be some book for this inequality.

Comment: OK. This formula is new to me, but it looks very interesting. It is a quantitative generalization of the fact that parallel forms are closed and co-closed. (See here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479991/geometric-interpretation-parallel-forms-are-harmonic).

Comment: Cool, I haven't realized this conclusion from this inequality if you don't  mention.

Comment: Also, is this a pointwise inequality which holds at every point, or an integral inequality? (for the integral norms).

Comment: @AsafShachar: It is pointwise, judging by the reference given by the OP (which, in turn, cites "Opérateur de courbure et laplacien des formes différentielles d’une variété riemannienne" by S. Gallot and D. Meyer).